# PageObject example with Ruby and Selenium webdriver only

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have driver object in env.rb file , now i want to initialize class and pass this driver/browser object through constuctor

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"

$googlehomepageobj = GoogleHome.new (driver)

class GoogleHome > Delegate (which class?)  
  def initialize(browser)
     super (browser)
  end
end
```

Which class i use for delegation? If PageObject is solution then please provide me simple example of Google login simple. I want to create pagewise objects into specific page class.

Comment: why you want delegation?

Comment: Then how we will pass driver object from env page to other classes? For e.g how to instantiate above GoogleHome class?

Comment: ok, i solved it without delegation.

Comment: I want to navigate to many pages within application then will same driver object will represent differnt browser pages? because i have used driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com" in GoogleHome class. Now if i click on serach button and navigate to next page then how same driver object will identify the elements on next page? I want to have different calsses for each navigation page. Please help me with example.